# Is it possible to move a string which starts with # after another string to the preceding line?

Tags: text-processing, vim, string

I have a script file that looks like this:

```bash
auditctl -a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S openat -F auid=1000      <TAB> #description of command....
auditctl -a ....                                                <TAB> #long description
```

*(Note the TAB characters before the comment.)*

Is possible with `sed`, or `awk`, or `vim` internal command to put the description after the `#` above the string itself so I will obtain
something like this:

```bash
#description of command....
auditctl -a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S openat -F auid=1000      


#long description
auditctl -a ....
```

I have tried with this `norm` command but the result is a disaster

```
:'<,'>norm f#D O P
```

Comment: You have tagged the question as `vim`. Does it mean that it must be a `vim`-based solution, or can it be purely `awk`-based for example (your question text implies that). In that case, please consider re-tagging the question as `text-processing` instead of mentioning a specific tool. Also, is it ensured that there can only be _one_ `#` on every line? Or are there also "pure" comment lines that should remain unchanged (such as what the description lines will look like after your text manipulation).

Comment: @elbarna you should update your sample input/output to include a case where the comment itself contains a `#` as most of the answers you're getting would fail given that as input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `sed`, one may use backreferences to matching patterns:

```
sed 's/\(PATTERN1\)\(PATTERN2\)/\2\n\1/'
```

Will reverse the two patterns and add a newline in between. PATTERN1 would be e.g. `^.*` i.e. any characters from the beginning of line, PATTERN2 `#.*$` i.e. a hash symbol followed by any number of characters until the end of line.

For deleting extra spaces, one might want to add this:

```
's/ *$//'
```

Best to also take care of comments with `#` in their own text by excluding the character in the match for the first portion via `[^#]`, i.e. any characters that are NOT `#`. Combined this makes it to:

```
sed 's/\(^[^#]*\)\(#.*$\)/\2\n\1/;s/ *$//'
```

Comment: Thanks, but on vim give me this error E194 No alternate file name to substitute for

:'#', outside vim works

Answer (score 4):

Using GNU awk for the 3rd arg to `match()` and `\S/\s` shorthand:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/([^#]*\S)\s*(#.*)/,a) { $0=a[2] ORS a[1] } 1' file
#description of command....
auditctl -a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S openat -F auid=1000
#long description
auditctl -a ....
```

or with any POSIX awk:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/[[:space:]]*#/) { $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH-1) ORS substr($0,1,RSTART-1) } 1' file
#description of # command....
auditctl -a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S openat -F auid=1000
#long description
auditctl -a ....
```

Note that the above will work no matter which characters the comment contains, including a `#`, and whether there are spaces before the comment or not, and it will strip any pre-comment spaces from the end of the rest of the line before printing it.

Comment: Thanks, but on vim give me this error E194 No alternate file name to substitute for

:'#', using this command without vim..works!

Comment: Then debug whatever vim problem you're having or use a different editor?

Comment: Minor issue: the POSIX version matches lines that are just comments too, adding an empty line after them.

Comment: @fra-san good point. The OP already accepted an answer though so my incentive to fix it for that case isn't high :-).

Answer (score 3):

The following `awk` program should do:

```
awk '/^ *[^ #].+#/{n=index($0,"#"); print substr($0,n); $0=substr($0,1,n-1)}1' input.sh
```

This will do the following

- We ensure that we only process lines whose first character (possible after leading space) is *not* the `#` sign, i.e. ensure that this is a comment after a command, not a "pure comment" line.
- If we are on such a line, determine the location of the first `#` and store it in `n`. Then we print the substring of the current line starting at that position on a line of its own. Afterwards, we "overwrite" the current line with only the part before the `#`. This approach can even handle situations where the comment part itself contains the `#` character.
- For all lines, we print them including any modifications possible made (this is the meaning of the seemingly "stray" `1` outside of the rule block).

Note that `awk` does not perform in-place editing of files, so you will have to redirect the output to a temporary file. Alternatively, if you have GNU Awk 4.1.0 or later, you can use the `-i inplace` extension for true in-place editing.

Answer (score 2):

I like the `rev` approach, having as example alternative cases as pointed by @Ed Morton:

Sample input file:

```bsh
auditctl -a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S openat -F auid=1000      #description of command....
auditctl -a ....                                                #long description
auditctl -a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S openat -F auid=1000#description of command....
auditctl -a ....                                                #long description# foo
auditctl -a ....                                                # long description#foo
```

```bsh
$ rev file | sed 's/^\(.*\)#[[:blank:]]*/\1#\n/' | rev
#description of command....
auditctl -a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S openat -F auid=1000
#long description
auditctl -a ....
#description of command....
auditctl -a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S openat -F auid=1000
#long description# foo
auditctl -a ....
# long description#foo
auditctl -a ....
```